# Update the permalink for one post via wp cli

Tags: permalinks, wp-cli

I'm using WP-CLI to import articles from a non-WordPress system. The legacy system has a custom URL defined for every post. I'd like to be able to set the permalink on the posts I'm importing base on the custom URL defined in the legacy system. I don't need to set the entire permalink, just being able to set the suffix, as is supported in the WP admin UI, would be sufficient. But there doesn't seem to be a way to change the permalink for a specific post using WP-CLI. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean the *post name* field, then we can update it for a post with:

```
wp post update 123 --post_name="new-slug"
```

where 123 is the post ID.

If we then try to update another post with the same post name:

```
wp post update 321 --post_name="new-slug"
```

then it will be set to `new-slug-2` in that case, as it needs to be unique. If we continue this with other posts, then we will get `new-slug-n` where `n` is a positive integer.